# Search across disperate fields, for rows containing a specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Pig
(
PigName VARCHAR(10),
Field1 VARCHAR(10),
Field2 VARCHAR(10),
Field3 VARCHAR(10),
Field4 VARCHAR(10),
Field5 VARCHAR(10),
Field6 VARCHAR(10),
Field7 VARCHAR(10),
Field8 VARCHAR(10),
Field9 VARCHAR(10),
Field10 VARCHAR(10),
Field11 VARCHAR(10)
)
```

If I was to search for all rows in #Pig where the string "eg" is in any of the columns do I have to use the following script or is there a more compact way of approaching this - maybe via a `TVP` ?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #Pig
WHERE   Field1 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field2 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field3 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field4 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field5 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field6 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field7 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field8 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field9 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field10 LIKE '%eg%' OR
        Field11 LIKE '%eg%'
```

**NOTE** each of the fields are the same data type but they are not actually connected....so normalising the data isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more compact way (and a more sensible way) to approach it would be to store pig names differently.

```
pig_num  pig_name
--
1        Wilbur
2        Peggy
3        Ominous
4        Portents
```

Then you could just write

```
select *
from pigs
where pig_name like '%eg%'
```

The CREATE TABLE statement for that table *might* look like this.

```
create table pigs (
  pig_num integer primary key,
  pig_name varchar(20) not null unique
);
```

Comment: ok - sorry - I need to edit the OP to make things a little clearer - the naming convention I used was just to make things easier to write

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to search for an arbitrary substring or would a word search work? If so, full text search may be a good answer.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Pig
(
    ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Pig PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    PigName VARCHAR(10),
    Field1 VARCHAR(10),
    Field2 VARCHAR(10),
    Field3 VARCHAR(10),
    Field4 VARCHAR(10),
    Field5 VARCHAR(10),
    Field6 VARCHAR(10),
    Field7 VARCHAR(10),
    Field8 VARCHAR(10),
    Field9 VARCHAR(10),
    Field10 VARCHAR(10),
    Field11 VARCHAR(10)
)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG mycatalog;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Pig
( 
    Field1 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field2 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field3 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field4 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field5 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field6 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field7 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field8 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field9 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field10 LANGUAGE 1033,
    Field11 LANGUAGE 1033
) 
KEY INDEX PK_Pig ON mycatalog; 
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Pig
WHERE   CONTAINS(*, '"peg*"') -- will find peg, peggy, but not jpeg.
```

Although FTS cannot search for arbitrary substrings, it can search for word prefixes (example above) and has other powerful capabilities. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx#supported

Full Text Search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

Comment: +1 looks like an interesting approach - I've not used these tools before.